# how to make into an array and also count

Tags: oracle

I have this data:

| app | asscs | mod_asscs |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 56 | cb-56 |
| a | 67 | cb-67 |
| b | 38 | cb-38 |
| a | 12 | 12 |

I want to group by column 'app' and count the cases where 'mod_asscs' value is equal to concat('cb-', asscs). I also want to output the array in a separate column 'mod_asscs_array' so that the output is the following:

| app | mod_asscs_array | scs_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | cb-56, cb-67 | 2 |
| b | cb-38 | 1 |

So far this is what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
app,
( CASE WHEN concat('cb-', asscs) = mod_asscs THEN mod_asscs || ',') AS mod_asscs_array,
COUNT( CASE WHEN concat('cb-', asscs) = mod_asscs THEN mod_asscs || ',') AS scs_count
FROM data_table
GROUP BY
app
```

Comment: What do you need to show for an "app" where the count is zero? Do you still need to show that "app" in the output, with a count of 0 and an empty array?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like aggregation.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (app, asscs, mod_asscs) as
  2    (select 'a', 56, 'cb-56' from dual union all
  3     select 'a', 67, 'cb-67' from dual union all
  4     select 'b', 38, 'cb-38' from dual union all
  5     select 'a', 12, '12'    from dual
  6    )
```

Query:

```
  7  select app,
  8         listagg(mod_asscs, ', ') within group (order by mod_asscs) array,
  9         count(*) cnt
 10  from test
 11  where mod_asscs = 'cb-'|| asscs
 12  group by app;

A ARRAY                       CNT
- -------------------- ----------
a cb-56, cb-67                  2
b cb-38                         1

SQL>
```

Comment: if there are duplicates in the array and I want unique values, do I do listagg(distinct.. ?

Comment: Up to Oracle 12c, you'll have to FIRST select distinct values, THEN use listagg. In later versions (19c and later), you can use listagg(distinct ...).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show all the "apps", even those with a "count" of zero, then you need conditional aggregation, something like this:

```
with
  test (app, asscs, mod_asscs) as (
    select 'a', 56, 'cb-56' from dual union all
    select 'a', 67, 'cb-67' from dual union all
    select 'b', 38, 'cb-38' from dual union all
    select 'a', 12, '12'    from dual union all
    select 'c', 33, 'cb-23' from dual
  )
select app,
       listagg(case when mod_asscs = 'cb-' || asscs
                    then mod_asscs end, ', ')
          within group (order by asscs) as mod_asscs_array,
       count(case when mod_asscs = 'cb-' || asscs
                  then mod_asscs end) as scs_count
from   test
group  by app
order  by app  -- if needed
;

APP MOD_ASSCS_ARRAY       SCS_COUNT
--- -------------------- ----------
a   cb-56, cb-67                  2
b   cb-38                         1
c                                 0
```

Comment: is ` 'cb-' || asscs` the same thing as  `concat('cb-', asscs)`? also if there are duplicates in the array, do I do `listagg(distinct.. ` and `count(distinct case when ...`?

Answer (score 0):

> if there are duplicates in the array, do I do `listagg(distinct..` and `count(distinct case when ...`?

You cannot use `LISTAGG(DISTINCT ...` as the `LISTAGG` function does not currently support the `DISTINCT` keyword; instead you need to use `DISTINCT` first in a sub-query and then use `LISTAGG`:

```sql
SELECT app,
       LISTAGG(mod_asscs, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY mod_asscs)
         AS mod_asscs_array,
       COUNT(*) AS scs_count
FROM   (
  SELECT DISTINCT 
         app,
         mod_asscs
  FROM   data_table
  WHERE  'cb-' || asscs = mod_asscs
)
GROUP BY app
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data_table (app, asscs, mod_asscs) AS
SELECT 'a', 56, 'cb-56' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 56, 'cb-56' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 67, 'cb-67' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 38, 'cb-38' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'a', 12, '12'    FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | APP | MOD_ASSCS_ARRAY | SCS_COUNT |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | a | cb-56,cb-67 | 2 |
> | b | cb-38 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=230b5f38e56862c28e07a1319fdf4fee)*